# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new on AngularJS and I got that error. Here is my code:

```
app.factory('NotificationService', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getNotificationList = function($http){
        var url = "http://some/url";
        return $http.get(url);
    }
    return factory;
});

app.controller('NotificationListController', function($scope,$http, NotificationService) {
    var notificationList = NotificationService.getNotificationList();
    notificationList.then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.notificationData = response.data;
        return response;
    });
});
```

I am so confuse where my mistake is. The error message is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined  at
>   Object.factory.getNotificationList
>   (http://localhost:63342/EmailNotification/js/email-angular.js:15:21)

Comment: `$http` is declared twice within the `factory`. For the 2nd declaration, the named parameter for `getNotificationList()`, you aren't providing an argument to give it a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because `$http` is undefined in your factory.

You can fix it by passing it to the factory like so:

```
app.factory('NotificationService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getNotificationList = function() { // Remove the `$http` parameter from here.
        var url = "http://some/url";
        return $http.get(url);
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: @twindicated70 accept it as an answer so if someone will encountered the same issue, he can easily check correct one

Comment: isn't this only necessary if they are minifying the js?

Answer (score 0):

Simple possible reason is `$http` is passed twice. When you pass any argument to the function, the closure for those variable changes

[see the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkfuoxjc/)

```
var a =10;
var b= 20;

var abc = function()
{
      document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = a + b;
}

var pqr = function(a,b)
{
      document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = a + b;
}

abc();
pqr();
```

In this example, though variable a,b declared, second function `pqr()` will return NaN, until we pass an argument, explicitly